# Matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I am very new to Python, I need to read numbers from a file and store them in a matrix like I would do it in fortran or C;

```
for i
  for j
    data[i][j][0]=read(0)
    data[i][j][1]=read(1)
    data[i][j][2]=read(2)
...
...
```

How can I do the same in Python? I read a bit but got confused with tuples and similar things

If you could point me to a similar example it would be great

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't come with multi-dimensional arrays, though you can add them through the popular [numpy](https://numpy.org/) third-party package.  If you want to avoid third-party packages, what you would do in Python would be to use a list of lists of lists (each "list" being a 1-D "vector-like" sequence, which can hold items of any type).

For example:

```
data = [ [ [0 for i in range(4)] for j in range(5)] for k in range(6)]
```

this makes a list of 6 items which are lists of 5 items which are lists of 4 0's -- i.e., a 6 x 5 x 4 "3D matrix" which you could then address the way you want,

```
for i in range(6):
  for j in range(5):
    data[i][j][0]=read(0)
    data[i][j][1]=read(1)
    data[i][j][2]=read(2)
```

to initialize the first three of the four items on each most-nested sublist with calls to that mysterious function `read` which presumably you want to write yourself (I have no idea what it's supposed to do -- not "read and return the next number" since it takes a mysterious argument, but, then what?).

Comment: instead of [0 for i in range(n)] one should use [0]*n

Comment: @unbeli, s/should/could/ -- `[0] * n` is faster but introduces an asymmetry that might prove extremely confusing to a newbie and induce them to use such replication elsewhere (on any layer but the deepest one), which would be an utter disaster.  I chose the more regular and perfectly symmetric approach very deliberately, believe me -- the one-off saving of a few microseconds at matrix initialization is not worth adding to a novice's disorientation;-).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your file format, but take a look on:

[Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html)
and
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use numpy and use the built in function for using I/O, in particular loadtxt.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

There are a lot of addictional functions to handle I/O:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple example would be:

```
data = []
with open(_filename_, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Matrices are two dimensional structures.  In plain Python, the most natural representation of a matrix is as a list of lists.

So, you can write a row matrix as:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

And write a column matrix as:

```
[[1],
 [2],
 [3],
 [4]]
```

This extends nicely to *m x n* matrices as well:

```
[[10, 20],
 [30, 40],
 [50, 60]]
```

See [*matfunc.py*](https://web.archive.org/web/20161223051703/http://users.rcn.com:80/python/download/matfunc.py) for an example of how to develop a full matrix package in pure Python.
The documentation for it is [*here*](https://web.archive.org/web/20161223052044/http://users.rcn.com:80/python/download/matfunc.htm).

And here is a worked-out example of doing matrix multiplication in plain python using a list-of-lists representation:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> def mmul(A, B):
        nr_a, nc_a = len(A), len(A[0])
        nr_b, nc_b = len(B), len(B[0])
        if nc_a != nr_b:
            raise ValueError('Mismatched rows and columns')
        return [[sum(A[i][k] * B[k][j] for k in range(nc_a))
                 for j in range(nc_b)] for i in range(nr_a)]

>>> A = [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> B = [[1],
         [2],
         [3],
         [4]]

>>> pprint(mmul(A, B))
[[30]]

>>> pprint(mmul(B, A), width=20)
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 4, 6, 8],
 [3, 6, 9, 12],
 [4, 8, 12, 16]]
```

As another respondent mentioned, if you get serious about doing matrix work, it would behoove you to install [*numpy*](https://numpy.org/) which has direct support for many matrix operations:

Answer (score 0):

A way to extend the list in a form to work like matrix. I have gone through other codes of matrix in python, all are using comprehensions to first initialize a list of required size and then update the values (which takes a little more time).
Let the r represents row and c for column.

`r = input('Enter row size: ')
c = input('Enter column size: ')
m = []
for i in range(r):
    m.append([])
    for j in range(c):
        m[i].append(input())
for i in m:
    print i`

Here, you can input the elements of matrix as it was in 'C' or equivalent languages. Hope this may help someone a different view of implementing matrices.